# Calling an object from module function

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables

I have the following problem: In my main I have some objcts (currently the button and later the car). I want to acces their functions from functions in a module.

first file (main):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from buttonActions import *
from Car import car

auto = car()

root = Tk()
root.title("RemoteCar")
root.state('zoomed')

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


stream = ttk.Frame(root, borderwidth=5, relief="ridge")
stream.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=2)

pil_image = Image.open("Bild.jpg")
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)

imgLabel = Label(stream, image=tk_image)
imgLabel.pack()


keys = ttk.Frame(root ,borderwidth=5, relief="ridge")
keys.grid(row=4, column=0)

buttonWidth = 8
buttonHight = 4


button_w = Button(keys, text='W', width=buttonWidth, height=buttonHight, bg='lightgrey', command={})
button_w.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.bind('<KeyPress-w>', w_down)
root.bind('<KeyRelease-w>', w_up)

root.mainloop()
```

second file:

```
from tkinter import Button
from RemoteCarActions import *

def w_down(event):
    global button_w
    button_w.config(bg='yellow')
    w_gedrueckt()
```

Error Message: NameError: in w_down button_w.config(bg='yellow') name 'button_w' is not defined. Am I using global wrong or what is the problem?

Comment: You cannot access widget in other module directly because it is in different namespace.  Pass the widget as an argument of `w_down()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Did you import your main file to the second one? You created an object of button in the first file, so you need to import object to the second like:

```
import main
main.button_w.config(bg='yellow')
```

Comment: Tried that, but doesnt work bc. second file is imported into first (Line 4 in first).

Comment: button_w is created into first file, it has to be imported to the second one. What is the name of your first file? Main or another?

Comment: You shouldn't answer the question if you need to ask questions yourself.  That is what the comment section is for.

Comment: My main file is the file I run so I can´t import it into the secondary file.

Answer (score 1):

For someone else: I got it working. First i tried to pass the button_w as an argument into w_down(). That didn´t work because tkinters bind() function gives the event as a argument. The solution is using lambda so both arguments are passed:

```
root.bind('<KeyPress-w>', lambda event, b=button_w: w_down(b))
```